# Django Stripe webhook json data how to view that data in admin

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin, stripe-payments

I can now send the webhook and it get received and return a 200 status to Stripe, but I don't understand how to get the information in the json.

```
{
  "object": {
    "id": "ch_1D2mVJEiQxrCiRvRgbqdtpbI",
    "object": "charge",
    "amount": 5000,
    "amount_refunded": 0,
    "application": null,
    "application_fee": null,
    "balance_transaction": "txn_1D2mVKEiQxrCiRvRAQ61MjSt",
    "captured": true,
    "created": 1535144857,
    "currency": "usd",
    "customer": null,
    "description": "A Django charge",
    "destination": null,
    "dispute": null,
    "failure_code": null,
    "failure_message": null,
    "fraud_details": {
    },
    "invoice": null,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "on_behalf_of": null,
    "order": null,
    "outcome": {
      "network_status": "approved_by_network",
      "reason": null,
      "risk_level": "normal",
      "seller_message": "Payment complete.",
      "type": "authorized"
    },
    "paid": true,
    "receipt_email": null,
    "receipt_number": null,
    "refunded": false,
    "refunds": {
      "object": "list",
      "data": [
      ],
      "has_more": false,
      "total_count": 0,
      "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1D2mVJEiQxrCiRvRgbqdtpbI/refunds"
    },
    "review": null,
    "shipping": null,
    "source": {
      "id": "card_1D2mVEEiQxrCiRvRTa2poVVT",
      "object": "card",
      "address_city": null,
      "address_country": null,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line1_check": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "address_state": null,
      "address_zip": null,
      "address_zip_check": null,
      "brand": "Visa",
      "country": "US",
      "customer": null,
      "cvc_check": null,
      "dynamic_last4": null,
      "exp_month": 9,
      "exp_year": 2021,
      "fingerprint": "p6BWjMSv83IqjoCg",
      "funding": "credit",
      "last4": "4242",
      "metadata": {
      },
      "name": "marie.pier.cm@gmail.com",
      "tokenization_method": null
    },
    "source_transfer": null,
    "statement_descriptor": null,
    "status": "succeeded",
    "transfer_group": null
  },
  "previous_attributes": null
}
```

I want to retrieve created (as a date), object.id, object.amount and object.paid, to be able to see then in django admin.

The code in views.py is

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    # Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON:
    jsondata = request.body
    data = json.loads(jsondata)

    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

the model i would like to populate is like this

```
class StripePayment(models.Model):
    paymentId = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    paymentAmount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    paid =  models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.paymentId
```

i know it would be something like

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
jsondata = request.body
    data = json.loads(jsondata)
    meta = copy.copy(request.META)
    for k, v in meta.items():
        if not isinstance(v, basestring):
            del meta[k]

    modelname.objects.create(
        .......)
```

but i cannot figure it out, please help :)

---

FIXED THIS WAY IF ANYONE NEEDS AT ONE POINT:
views.py

```
  @require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    # Do something with event

    return HttpResponse(status=200)

    paymentId = payload['object:id']
    amount = payload['object:amount']
    paid = payload['paid']

    StripePayment.objects.create(
        paymentId=paymentId,
        amount=amount,
        paid=paid,
    )
```

and models.py

```
class StripePayment(models.Model):
paymentId = models.CharField(max_length=150)
amount = models.CharField(max_length=150)
paid = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking here. What is that stuff with `request.META` about? Why would you do that? Why can't you just call your create method with the four pieces of data from the posted JSON?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i added some code at the end of the post but its not working could you maybe look at it and let me know what you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get nested data via things like `payload['object:id']`. You need to treat each level as a separate dictionary, which it is:

```
payment_id = payload['object']['id']
amount = payload['object']['amount']
paid = payload['object']['paid']
```

Also note, your `return` is just before this code, so the rest will never be executed. You should move that return to the end of the function.

Comment: oh ok thank you so much for the information i hope you have a great day :D